# Why does trunc() return 0?

Tags: c++, truncate

- [Unit test fails even though values are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120294/unit-test-fails-even-though-values-are-equal)

I was stuck in the above problem.

While trying to solve that, I wrote the following listing.

I expect it to keep two digits after the decimal point.

```
#include "simulation.hpp"
#include <cstdio>

typedef double real;

double truncate_(double f)
{
    return std::trunc(f * 100.0);
}

int main()
{
    //Simulation sim;
    //sim.run();
    LennardJones lj(Constants::EPSILON, Constants::SIGMA, Constants::KB);

    Vec3 diatance(4.0, 4.0, 4.0);

    real attractive = lj.getPotentialAttractive(diatance);
    real repulsive = lj.getPotentialRepulsive(diatance);

    std::cout << attractive << std::endl;
    std::cout << repulsive << std::endl;

    real attractive2 = truncate_(attractive);
    real repulsive2 = truncate_(repulsive);

    std::cout << attractive2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << repulsive2 << std::endl;

    getchar(); // Wait for a keypress
}
```

**Output:**

```
-4.84292e-06
6.82474e-08
-0
0
```

Comment: What do you think it *should* return? Both inputs are < 1.0, so they truncate to 0. Works as documented.

Comment: @DevSolar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120294/unit-test-fails-even-though-values-are-equal

Comment: @user366312 I still don't see what else you expect?

Comment: @user17732522, I expect it to keep two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @user366312 You mean two digits (before the comma) after the multiplication with `100`? It did do that.

Comment: The larger absolute value of the two inputs is -4.84292e-06, meaning -0.00000484292. That's still zero to within two digits after the decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-4.84292e-06` and `6.82474e-08` are still zero within two digits after the decimal point, so as expected, you're getting zero when truncating them.

If you wrote

```cpp
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
```

... then you would print `0.00` instead of `0`. It keeps two digits after the decimal point, and both those digits are zero.